# For $x$, $y$, $z$ the sides of a triangle, show $\sum_{cyc}\frac{yz((y+z)^2-x^2)}{(y^2+z^2)^2}\ge\frac{9(y+z-x)(x+z-y)(x+y-z)}{4xyz}$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

in $\triangle ABC$, let $AB=z,BC=x,AC=y$,show  that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{yz((y+z)^2-x^2)}{(y^2+z^2)^2}\ge\frac{9(y+z-x)(x+z-y)(x+y-z)}{4xyz}$$

by well kown Iran 96 inequality
$$(xy+yz+xz)\left(\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+z)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(x+z)^2}\right)\ge\dfrac{9}{4}$$

Comment: I have a proof by C-S and uvw,

Comment: maybe have without uvw methods?

Comment: We can use SOS here, but it's very ugly.

Comment: I want to see a solution which use SOS

Comment: From where does this inequality come?

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{yz}{(y^2+z^2)^2(x+y-z)(x+z-y)}\geq\frac{9}{4xyz(x+y+z)}.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{yz}{(y^2+z^2)^2(x+y-z)(x+z-y)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2z^2}{yz(y^2+z^2)^2(x+y-z)(x+z-y)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}yz(y^2+z^2)^2(x+y-z)(x+z-y)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$4xyz(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)^2\geq9\sum\limits_{cyc}yz(y^2+z^2)^2(x+y-z)(x+z-y)$$ or
$$\sum_{sym}(9x^7y-18x^6y^2+27x^5y^3-18x^4y^4-9x^5y^2z+4x^4y^3z+4x^4y^2z^2+x^3y^3z^2)\geq0$$ or
$$9\sum_{cyc}xy(x^6-2x^5y+3x^4y^2-4x^3y^3+3x^2y^4-2xy^5+y^6)-$$
$$-9xyz\sum_{cyc}xy(x^3-x^2y-xy^2+y^3)-xyz\sum_{cyc}(5x^3y^2+5x^3z^2-8x^3yz-2x^2y^2z)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2xy(9(x^2+y^2)^2-9xyz(x+y)-5z^4-xyz^2)\geq0$$ or
$$7\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2xy(x^4+y^4-z^4)+$$
$$+\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2xy(2z^4-xyz^2-9xy(x+y)z+2(x^4+9x^2y^2+y^4))\geq0.$$

We'll prove that $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2xy(x^4+y^4-z^4)\geq0.$$ 
Indeed, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2xy(x^4+y^4-z^4)\geq$$
$$\geq(x-z)^2xz(x^4+z^4-y^4)+(y-z)^2yz(y^4+z^4-x^4)\geq$$
$$\geq(y-z)^2xz(x^4-y^4)+(y-z)^2yz(y^4-x^4)=$$
$$=z(y-z)^2(x^4-y^4)(x-y)\geq0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$2z^4-xyz^2-9xy(x+y)z+2(x^4+9x^2y^2+y^4)\geq0.$$ 
We'll prove that:
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4+9x^2y^2+y^4}{11}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}.$$
Let $x^2+y^2=2uxy$.

Thus, $u\geq1$ and we need to prove that:
$$\left(\frac{x^4+9x^2y^2+y^4}{11}\right)^3\geq\left(\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}\right)^4$$ or
$$\left(\frac{4u^2-2+9}{11}\right)^3\geq\frac{(2u+2)^2}{16}$$ or $f(u)\geq0,$ where
$$f(u)=3\ln(4u^2+7)-2\ln(u+1)+2\ln2-3\ln11.$$
But $$f'(u)=\frac{24u}{4u^2+7}-\frac{2}{u+1}>0,$$ which says $f(u)\geq f(1)=0.$

Also, by AM-GM $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}\geq\sqrt{xy}.$$

Now, let $z=t\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}.$

Thus,
$$2z^4-xyz^2-9xy(x+y)z+2(x^4+9x^2y^2+y^4)\geq$$
$$\geq2z^4-\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}\right)^2z^2-18\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}\right)^3z+22\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}\right)^4=$$
$$=\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}}\right)^4(2t^4-t^2-18t+22)\geq0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: at last inequality how to get $2t^4-t^2-18t+22$,becase I found you maybe something is not right,

Comment: because it must to show this $2z^4-xyz^2-9xyz(x+y)z+2(x^4+9x^2y^2+y^4)\ge 0$,and I think the following it equaliment something wrong

Comment: use you it must to show $2z^4-xyz^2-9xy(x+y)z+22(xy)^2\ge 0$,then How to following step?

Comment: @function sug I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks you,I have understand

Comment: why $\sum_{cyc}xy(x-y)^2(x^4+y^4-z^4)\ge 0$?

Comment: @communnites I added something. See now.